# Can you use multiple elifs for one variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a text game in python three and I need to use multiple elifs, like this:

```
VARIABLE = input ("Prompt Here")
if VARIABLE == ("Possible Answer 1"):
  print ("Reward Text")
elif VARIABLE == ("Possible Answer 2"):
  print ("Reward Text")
elif VARIABLE == ("Possible Answer 3"):
  print ("Reward Text")
```

Comment: Yes, you can use multiple `elif`s.

Comment: Why don't you just run your code and find out?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer : Yes.

However, on a minimal example like this, you may consider alternative ways to achieve this with less conditionnals, such as :

```
results = { "Possible Answer 1":"Game response 1",
    "Possible Answer 2":"Game response 2",
    "Possible Answer 3":"Game response 3" }
if VARIABLE in results:
    print (results[VARIABLE])
# else :
#     default action, if appliable
```

Take the good habit of keeping execution path simple and separating data from behavior whenever possible !